# Class meta got invalid attributes

Tags: django, python-2.7

Please help to fix this Meta class value as I gave up after detailed research.
I am getting back error while trying to handle template urls with "get_absolute_url" as it responds with following error.

> TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): sale_price,get_absolute_url.

Below is my code.

```
class Meta:
        db_table = 'products'
        ordering = ['-created_at']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

        @models.permalink
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return ('catalog_product', (), {'product_slug': self.slug})

        def sale_price(self):
            if self.old_price > self.price:
                return self.price
            else:
                return None
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how models are defined. You add your methods and attributes to the actual `Model` class and use the `Meta` class to specify options upon the class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    old_price = ...
    price = ...
    slug = ...
    created_at = ...
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('catalog_product', (), {'product_slug': self.slug})

    def sale_price(self):
        if self.old_price > self.price:
            return self.price
        else:
            return None
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

Have a read of the [Model documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/) and pay attention to the section on [Meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-options)

**EDIT**

Also, don't use the `permalink` decorator as it's no longer recommended:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator

> The permalink decorator is no longer recommended. You should use reverse() in the body of your get_absolute_url method instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Timmy you rally sum this up for me.