# python_2_unicode_compatible error; python 2.7, django 1.9

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unicode-string

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.9.7.  I am trying to add a string method to models.py but I'm getting an error.
When I run "python manage.py runserver", I get the following:

ValueError: @python_2_unicode_compatible cannot be applied to Languages because it doesn't define __ str__().

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Languages(models.Model):
    langid = models.AutoField(db_column='LangID', primary_key=True)
    lname = models.CharField(db_column='lName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'languages'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lname
```

This is very similar to the following Question: [python_2_unicode_compatible error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741754/python-2-unicode-compatible-error)

But the problem there was that Django was not a new enough version. Clearly there is something different going on here. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: your snippet works fine on my computer. maybe try using 4 spaces instead of blank lines (say between lname and class Meta and before the definition of __str__)

Comment: @Ringil thanks, I checked but it doesn't seem to be an indentation problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.lname
```

Then you are over-riding the in-built 'str' method.
So whenever str is used, your defined method is called instead of the in-built one.

So if you all you want to do is to return the "lname" of the object of the model "Languages", then you can use a different name of the def like this

```
    def lang_name(self):
        return u'%s' % self.lname
```

This u'%s' solves your problem of unicode to string.

Now, if you don't want to use other name of the def, but want to override the in-built 'str' function, then the below should work for you:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.lname
```

Though, by default Django models have the following function, which returns the default value for an object:

```
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.lname
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives me an error though: "TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): lang_name". Also the Django official tutorial documentation gave me the original code for def __ str__(self): return self.lname  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: def lang_name(self): needs to be defined in the model and not under the Meta class as it is a property of the object of that model.
Whereas in class Meta, you define representation (example -> ordering of objects, verbose_name etc) of the objects and not where you decide a new property for the objects
See this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564001/class-meta-got-invalid-attributes

There are some pre-defined Meta options which you can use -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by simply restarting the server.

```
Ctrl+C
```

and thereafter;

```
python manage.py runserver
```